# App Crash on Services Response

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, crash, nsurlconnection

I have integrated the services to my application.
I am testing my application its get crashes occasionally.

**error is The Internet connection appears to be offline.**

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    @try{
        if(self.target != nil && self.action  && [self.target respondsToSelector:self.action]) {
            NSLog(@"error is %@",[error localizedDescription]);
            IMP imp = [self.target methodForSelector:self.action];
            id (*func)(id, SEL, id) = (void *)imp;
            func(self.target, self.action, [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"main: Caught %@: %@", [exception name], [exception reason]);
    }
}
```

IT says Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code= 1 address=0x123451)
at the below line

```
 func(self.target, self.action, [error localizedDescription]);
```

No idea why its crashes.  Its really frustrating me unable to know why suddenly the application crashes.

I enable **All Exceptions** for the project its trigger that line.  On click continues its still says same line.

Comment: Does your self.target take exactly one inparameter of type id or NSString?

Comment: Also unless you are trying to do something really magical with this why don't you just use performSelector. Like [self.target performSelector:self.action withObject:[error localizedDescription]];

Comment: Its take an id for target                                                                                               services.action = @selector(responseData:);
 -(void) responseData:(id) response

Comment: Then I see mo issues with this unless something gets cleaned up by ARC. Have you tried substituting self.action for @selector(responseData:) directly? In all three places preferably. Also check so [self.target methodForSelector:self.action] actually returns a implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only getting this problem in the simulator, then it may be that you need to restart the simulator. I've noticed lately that the simulator will sometimes cause all HTTP requests to error out with that for no reason and only restarting it clears the issue.

Also, I have found that some HTTP errors can end up with a nil localizedDescription on the error object. What are you seeing on the NSLog line where you print that out?